# Using fields in attribute table to generate new polygon

Tags: qgis, polygon, attribute-table

Is it possible to use fields in the attribute table to duplicate/ generate a new polygon with the field information?

I have a series of numbered polygons (Features) which I want to be able to link to a new polygon/layer (i.e. Roman Features/ Medieval Features etc). Currently, I am having to select each polygon and then copy it and paste it into the layer I need.

[[image: the "features" are in grey here and i'd like to add them to the correct periods layer like in the second image without copy/pasting ][1]]

[image: periods layers]

Comment: You want to copy a (in field) specified number of times features from a layer **a** to a layer **b**?

Comment: Select by expression based an an attribute. Copy the selected features and paste them to a new layer.